# Solving for $m$ in $F=G\Big(\dfrac{mM}{r^2}\Big)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve for $m$ in $F=G\Big(\dfrac{mM}{r^2}\Big)$

I ended up with $\frac{F}{G}\frac{r^2}{M}=m.$ Can I simplify it further or did I completely mess up the answer? I got to where I was by dividing both sides by $G$ then multiplying it by $r^2$ and the n dividing by $M$.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I guess that's it. There are no further simplifications.

Comment: One thing though, if $G$ was a function, then things would be slightly different. Let $G^{-1}$ denote the inverse of $G$. Then $m = \dfrac{r^2}{M} G^{-1}(F).$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align*}
&F=G\left(\frac{mM}{r^2}\right) \\ 
&\implies \frac{F}{G}=\frac{mM}{r^2} \space \text{Dividing both sides by }G \\
&\implies \frac{F}{G M}=\frac{m}{r^2} \space \text{Dividing both sides by }M \\
&\implies \frac{r^2 F}{G M}=m \space \text{Multiplying both sides by }r^2 
\end{align*}
$$

---

Note also that, for your answer

$$\frac{F}{G}\frac{r^2}{M}=\frac{F r^2}{GM}=m$$

which is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that for me

Comment: @user38799 No problem!  Glad I could help.